# Tabletool with datatable

Tags: asp.net

I using below code to add export functionality in datatable. i am unable to see export button, i am using master page. can anybody give some valuable remarks

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tblOscarNominees').dataTable({
             "bJQueryUI": true,
               "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aaSorting": [[4, "desc"]],
                                    "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
                "oTableTools": {
                    "aButtons": [
            "copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf",
            {
                "sExtends": "collection",
                "sButtonText": "Save",
                "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
            }
        ]
```

}

Below is the reference i set in master page

```
        <link href="DataTables/media/css/TableTools_JUI.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<link href="DataTables/media/css/TableTools.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />




<link href="DataTables/css/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script src="../DataTables/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../DataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../DataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.editable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../DataTables/js/jquery.jeditable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../DataTables/js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../DataTables/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../DataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="../DataTables/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../DataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script src="DataTables/media/js/TableTools.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="DataTables/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: done it by adding below line
    "oTableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath": "../DataTables/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
               
                           }

Comment: please answer your question instead of commenting. Then, mark your answer as the answer. This will flag the question as answered